# MySQL Order By a column ASC/DESC related to another Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns in database like this:

```
ColumnA ColumnB
NULL    1
2       1
NULL    3
1       3
NULL    2
1       2
```

I want to:

First step， sort columnA placing the NULL rows on the top, then the NotNull rows. So it should be:

```
NULL     1
NULL     3
NULL     2
2        1
1        3
1        2
```

Second step (what I want to get at the end), sort columnB, asc columnB when columnA is Null but desc columnB when columnA is NotNull, so it should be:

```
NULL     1
NULL     2
NULL     3
1        3
1        2
2        1
```

So, how can I make a single mysql query to get it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
select a, b
from t
order by (a is null) desc,  -- put null values on top
         (case when a is null then b end) asc,
         b desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
select a,b from t order by a, case when a is null then b end, b desc
```

or maybe...

```
SELECT a,b FROM t ORDER BY a,CASE WHEN a IS NULL THEN b* -1 ELSE b END DESC;
```

Comment: I thought there would be a simpler answer.

Comment: Follow your suggestion, all the results ordered by columnB asc, the 'b desc' part didn't take effect.